# Using a Filter in searchTwitter package in R

Tags: r, filter, twitter, sentiment-analysis, social-media

I am using the code below to extract tweets with #walmart. I would like 1200 tweets but I want to exclude tweets that have #walmarthelp as a second hashtag.

```
tweets_a <- searchTwitter("#walmart", n = 1200, lang = "en", since="2020-09-13")
```

A simple filter after the tweets are extracted will reduce the critical component of `n=1200`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this uses Twitter's search, the best bet would be using that to your advantage. Twitter allows you to exclude terms using `-`(minus) within the search query. In your case, `"#walmart -#walmarthelp"` should exclude the Walmart Help hashtag.